# How can I make a Pandas data_frame column based on "If any observation in a particular column meets a condition, then True?"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable that I want to define as `True` if any item in its containing group meets the condition.  For example, in the below `.csv` frame, a column `D` corresponding to the condition I'm looking at would be True for all rows where `A==1` because it's true in the first row, `False` for `A==4` because it's False in the only row there, `True` for `A==6` because two values are `True`, and `False` for all rows where `A==8` because none are true.

```
A,B,C
1,2,True
1,4,False
1,5,False
4,5,False
6,7,True
6,4,False
6,5,True
8,9,False
8,11,False
8,20,False
```

I've tried using the `.any()` method, but it keeps returning an empty data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on `A` and then use `transform` which keeps the the same shape as the original dataframe. Apply a `lambda` function where you test if any member of the corresponding group in column `C` is True.

```
df['D'] = df.groupby('A').C.transform(lambda group: group.any())

>>> df
   A   B      C      D
0  1   2   True   True
1  1   4  False   True
2  1   5  False   True
3  4   5  False  False
4  6   7   True   True
5  6   4  False   True
6  6   5   True   True
7  8   9  False  False
8  8  11  False  False
9  8  20  False  False
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for.  If instead of `C` being pure boolean values it was a bunch of integers and I wanted to check for `C==2` for that condition, how would I do that?  I haven't been able to figure out how to put those arguments in the `any()` function.

Comment: `lambda group: group == 2`.  Wouldn't `df.C == 2` also work?

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  And I don't think so  because it needs to be true for each group, not for the data frame as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
In [7]: df.C.groupby(df.A).max()
Out[7]: 
A
1     True
4    False
6     True
8    False
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

Your question didn't specify what should happen if some of the rules contradict others, e.g., if there's also a row

```
1,2,False
```

The code above would still decide that the value of 1 is `True`, as *some* of the rows had

```
1,2,True
```

You can change it to require that *all* of the rows must be `True`, by changing `max` to `min` in the above.

---

Finally, to add a new column based on the results, you can `merge`:

```
pd.merge(
     df, 
     df.C.groupby(df.A).max().reset_index().rename(columns={'C': 'is_true'}))
```

Comment: If there's a row `1,2,False`, then I'd still mark it True because one of them is true.